# Simple ACF Plots for different time series

Tags: time-series, correlation, autocorrelation

I am trying to find which lag of variable x has the highest correlation with variable y.

I know that ACF plots are for the the same time series on itself, but is there anything wrong with looking at an "ACF" plot with two different time series to figure out which lag should be regressed onto the other variable?

Comment: ACF means auto-correlation function, and auto means "self".  What would your version of a plot consist of?

Comment: @rolando2 yes. I know that ACFs are for auto-correlations. I want to know which lags of one variable is correlated with another variable.

Comment: I'm asking what is this "ACF" (your quotes) plot that would link 2 variables?

Comment: Sorry, I put ACF in quotes because it is not technically an ACF plot since I am correlating one variable on lags of another as opposed to itself.

Comment: Let's call your idea a "cross-series lagged correlation plot."  I can imagine a way to create one through a rather laborious process, but not using any pre-existing standard software commands that I know of.  How did you envision creating it?

Comment: I would modify the code in this blog post to lag on y instead of on x then do many correlations of x on lags of y http://www.business-science.io/timeseries-analysis/2017/08/30/tidy-timeseries-analysis-pt-4.html        `my_time_series_tbl %>%
    tq_mutate(
        select     = value,
        mutate_fun = lag.xts,
        k          = 1:5
    )`